# VBScript to color input text field

Tags: html, vbscript, colors, field

I have the below code.

I have an input text field which has an example value grey colored. When clicking on the field, the text is erased and color is set to black. Then, after it finishes some VBScript, the fields are cleared and the example is back in the input field, but I cannot get it to also color it grey at this point.

Everything works fine except UserName.style = "color: #ccc;" in the VBScript.

Am I missing something here? VB error says "Not implemented"

Any solution highly appreciated.
Thank you.

VBScript:

```
UserName.value = "Example: JSmith"
UserName.style = "color: #ccc;"
</SCRIPT>
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="UserName" value="Example: JSmith" style="color: #ccc;"  onfocus="myFunction(UserName)"><p>
```

JavaScript:

```
function myFunction(x)
{
x.style.color="black";
x.value="";
}
```

Comment: try `UserName.setAttribute "style", "color: #ccc;"`

Comment: I assume you mean asp.net?

Comment: how about #cccccc ...

Comment: tried UserName.setAttribute "style", "color: #ccc;" with both #ccc and #cccccc. Error message no longer displayed but font does not change to #ccc

Answer (score 1):

VBScript/.HTA demo:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <Title>colortext</Title>
  <hta:application id="colortext" scroll = "no">
  <script type="text/vbscript">
   Function CBT()
     ' change backgound color of txtDemo
     Dim txtDemo : Set txtDemo = document.getElementById("txtDemo")
     Select Case txtDemo.style.backgroundColor
       Case "black"
         txtDemo.style.backgroundColor = "yellow"
       Case "yellow"
         txtDemo.style.backgroundColor = "red"
       Case Else
         txtDemo.style.backgroundColor = "black"
     End Select
   End Function
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <input type="text" id="txtDemo" value="Initial Value" />
  <hr />
  <input type="button" value="CBT" onclick="CBT" />
 </body>
</html>
```

The important part is to get the HTML element `document.getElementById("txtDemo")` and its
`.style.backgroundColor` property.

Comment: Not really what I wanted. The font color needs to change on focus and revert back when the script is finished. I figured out the solution, will post it in a sec. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

VBScript:

```
Call initialColor()
UserName.value = "Example: JSmith"
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="UserName" value="Example: JSmith" style="color: #ccc;"  onfocus="myFunction(UserName)"><p>
```

JavaScript:

```
function changeColor(x)
{
x.style.color="black";
x.value="";
}
function initialColor()
{
UserName.style.color="ccc";
Manager.style.color="ccc";
Ticket.style.color="ccc";
}
```